# How to create multiple polygons using text-based coordinates?

Tags: arrays, text, polygon, arcpy

I am trying to loop through 3 text files containing XY coordinates. I need to read the coordinates and use them to build polygon features all in a single loop. Additionally, I need to add two fields describing the polygons. I am able to create 3 tables with the new fields, but there is no polygon visible at the end of my loop. It seems that i am not able to arcpy.Polygon the array of points i create, or the variable representing the polygon object is not being placed where i need it to go.

I am successfully able to open read and parse the text lines from each of the files. I am defining the XY coordinates as points and adding those points to an array. From that array of points, i try to make a polygon feature. Using insert cursur i define the fields i wish to write to and then use insert Rows. If i print out the list(polygon) whish contains the polygons geometry, the coordinates are present, I just don't know why it isn't being written into the shapefile.

```
#setting up my functionality and my environment
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'G:\Fall19\program\lab2\data\data'
env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.qualifiedFieldNames = "UNQUALIFIED"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#figuring the the textfiles that need to be managed
import os, glob
os.chdir(r'G:\Fall19\program\lab2\data\data\districts')

text_file=[i for i in glob.glob("*.txt")]
text_file
#creating a new shapefile that is ready to be imported into
poly=arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env.workspace, "districts.shp", 
"POLYGON")

#adding the two extra fields needed by the instructions
arcpy.AddField_management(poly, "vert_count", "DOUBLE", 100, "", "", "", 
"NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(poly, "dist_id", "DOUBLE", 100, "", "", "", 
"NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")

#the single loop function that will open the files, pull the coordintes, 
convert the coordinates to points
#create a polygon from the points and write to the new shapefile created 
above. 
for t in range(len(text_file)):
    with open(text_file[t]) as text:
        lines= text.readlines() 
        list_coord=[i.split('\t') for i in lines]
        list_coord.remove(['X', 'Y\n']) #i now have a nested lists of 
coordinated [x, y]
        xs=[]
        ys=[]
        array= arcpy.Array() #the array is created beforehand and added 
to later
        #two seperate lists of x and y coordinates will be used later 
with the arcpy.point function
        for coord in list_coord:
            xs.append(coord[0])
            ys.append(coord[1])
        for i in range(len(list_coord)):
            point= arcpy.Point(xs[i], ys[i]) #the xy coordinates now 
created a point feature which then gets added to the array above
            array.add(point)
        shape= arcpy.Polygon(array) #this should be creating polygon 
geometry from the aray feature can be displayed using  list(shape)
        #these are the two fiends that also need to be written into the 
shapefile
        vert_count=len(list_coord)
        dist_id= text_file[t][-5]
        #i believe this is where i am having issues as the count and id 
get written over, but there seems to be no geometry
        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(poly,['Shape@', 'vert_count', 
'dist_id'])
        cursor.insertRow([shape, vert_count, dist_id])
    del cursor
```

I expect to get 1 shapefile with 3 separate polygons. Each of those polygons will have unique geometry, number of coordinates, and id. I get the vertices count and id fields, but it does not look like the geometry is being written over.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working in my environment, starting from two txt files, poligono1.txt:

```
X   Y
-46,9   -23,3
-46,3   -23,3
-46,3   -24
-46,9   -24
```

And poligono2.txt:

```
X   Y
-52,8   -22,1
-52,1   -22,1
-52,1   -22,7
-52,8   -22,7
```

I created the two polygons with the expected information in the columns:

[image: polygons generated by script]

Here is your script pointing to my files:

```
#setting up my functionality and my environment
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'C:\Teste\createPolygons'
env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.qualifiedFieldNames = "UNQUALIFIED"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#figuring textfiles that need to be managed
import os, glob
os.chdir(r'C:\Teste\createPolygons\districts')

text_file=[i for i in glob.glob("*.txt")]
text_file
#creating a new shapefile that is ready to be imported into
poly=arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env.workspace, "districts.shp", 
"POLYGON")

#adding the two extra fields needed by the instructions
arcpy.AddField_management(poly, "vert_count", "DOUBLE", 100, "", "", "", 
"NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(poly, "dist_id", "DOUBLE", 100, "", "", "", 
"NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")

#the single loop function that will open the files, pull the coordinates, convert the coordinates to points
#create a polygon from the points and write to the new shapefile created above. 
for t in range(len(text_file)):
    with open(text_file[t]) as text:
        lines= text.readlines() 
        list_coord=[i.split('\t') for i in lines]
        list_coord.remove(['X', 'Y\n']) #i now have a nested lists of coordinates [x, y]
        xs=[]
        ys=[]
        array= arcpy.Array() #the array is created beforehand and added to later
        #two separate lists of x and y coordinates will be used later with the arcpy.point function
        for coord in list_coord:
            xs.append(coord[0])
            ys.append(coord[1])
        for i in range(len(list_coord)):
            point= arcpy.Point(xs[i], ys[i]) #the xy coordinates now created a point feature which then gets added to the array above
            array.add(point)
        shape= arcpy.Polygon(array) #this should be creating polygon geometry from the array feature - can be displayed using list(shape)
        #these are the two fields that also need to be written into the shapefile
        vert_count=len(list_coord)
        dist_id= text_file[t][-5]
        #i believe this is where i am having issues as the count and id get written over, but there seems to be no geometry
        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(poly,['Shape@', 'vert_count', 
'dist_id'])
        cursor.insertRow([shape, vert_count, dist_id])
    del cursor
```

You can search for your files in your folders and look for anything unusual, like folders security access, etc. Because your code works.

P.S.: I have a tip, generate all the points in a point feature and see if they are coerent to form polygons.